# Custom/compound view: NoSuchMethodError for LinearLayout constructor

Tags: android, constructor, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view, android-compound-view

I have an Android library, [`LabelledSpinner`](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/LabelledSpinner) which is essentially a compound view that holds a `Spinner` with `TextView`s, all in a `LinearLayout`.

However, when I run the app on Android 4 devices (my library supports Android 4 upwards), I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class com.farbod.labelledspinner.LabelledSpinner  
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>
  at com.farbod.labelledspinner.LabelledSpinner.<init>(LabelledSpinner.java:117)
  at com.farbod.labelledspinner.LabelledSpinner.<init>(LabelledSpinner.java:112)
  at com.farbod.labelledspinner.LabelledSpinner.<init>(LabelledSpinner.java:108)
...
```

Users of my library encountered [the same issue](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/LabelledSpinner/issues/28).

Here are my constructors (you can also view the entire file [on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/LabelledSpinner/blob/master/labelledspinner/src/main/java/com/farbod/labelledspinner/LabelledSpinner.java)) - note that this file `extends LinearLayout`:

```
public LabelledSpinner(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public LabelledSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public LabelledSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initializeLayout(context, attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public LabelledSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initializeLayout(context, attrs);
}
```

I think the error points specifically to the third constructor (the line references in the error aren't exactly clear to me).

I find it strange that I am given this error, as looking at the `LinearLayout` class, the constructors I am using are available:

```
public LinearLayout(Context context) {...}

public LinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {...}

public LinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {...}

public LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    ...
}
```

I am not getting this issue on Android Lollipop devices.

Comment: try  to use one previous version of same library. https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/LabelledSpinner/releases  , this was written in last answer in the link you have in your question.

Comment: @vabhivab What exactly do you mean? If you mean using a previous version of the library, I am aware of that, but I make the library, so I am trying to find a method of fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in my case, my app was using an outdated version of the library (to be specific, I had not pushed the updates from my library to Bintray).

More information [on the comment on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/LabelledSpinner/issues/28#issuecomment-197724765).